# tomcat eclipse java ee default package

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, http-status-code-404, default-package

I'm trying to set up a dynamic web app using Eclipse Juno and Tomcat 7. My problem is that i can only get my servlet to run if my file structure is

MyProject/Java Rescources/src/(default package)/MyServlet.java

I've read i should avoid using the default package (don't know why) but when i try to use a different package:

MyProject/Java Resources/src/myPackage/MyServlet.java

I get the error message:

HTTP Status 404 - /MyProject/MyServlet 
The requested resource is not available

Its only a small test project so i can start a new workspace and create the project anew if necessary. I suppose i have to change a path somewhere but i don't know where or how.

I got it working using the following in web.xml

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>QNumInput</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>myPackage.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>QNumInput</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/QNumInput/QNumReq.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The index.html file calls this with the  tag:

```
<form name="getQNumForm" 
            action="http://localhost:8080/MyProject/QNumInput/QNumReq.do" 
            METHOD = "POST"> 
<B>Enter Question Number 1 to 200</B>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="qNumber">
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Request Question Text">
</form>
```

It did not work at first so i cleaned the tomcat work directory by right clicking on the server (not sure if this is necessary) It still did not work so i gave up and exited Eclipse. This must have saved the new settings because when i fired up Eclipse again and tried it again it worked ok.
Thanks for the help.
DG

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make sure your `<servlet-mapping>` and `<servlet>` elements in web.xml are correctly set.

Comment: Thanks,I got it working using the following in web.xml:<servlet>
     <servlet-name>QNumInput</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>myPackage.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>QNumInput</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/QNumInput/QNumReq.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>